# Apply Rotation to popup

Tags: swift, xcode

I am using PopupDialog which is a subclass of `UIViewController` and would like to force the rotation of just this view upon popup.

here is an example of what I would like to do:

```
import UIKit
import PopupDialog

class TestViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}
func presentpopup() {
    let popup = PopupDialog(title: "Title", message: "My message", image: nil)
    let buttonOne = CancelButton(title: "cancel") {}
    let buttonTwo = DefaultButton(title: "go to settings", dismissOnTap: false){
        print("pressed")
    }
    //****** Here is where I would like to rotate the entire view***/////
    popup.addButtons([buttonOne, buttonTwo])
    self.present(popup, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

What I would like is something along the line of  `popup.rotate(.pi/2)`. Is this possible? I can't Seem to figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

```
popup.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -.pi/2)
```

This rotates the view 90 degrees. it can be applied to any view.